# Is it able to show some components only when input method is active?

Tags: android, android-input-method

In an android application, I want to show some components only when the input method is active, e.g. to change the font size and color.

Is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TextWatcher interface while input method is running in edittext.

[Refer This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)